# How Does GitHub Use SSL without "www" in their URL?

Tags: url, ssl, github, ssl-certificate

I recently noticed that GitHub uses SSL with this URL: `https://github.com`

[image]

What kind of SSL cert do they use to do this?

Is there any special server configuration needed to pull this off?

Comment: This question refers to professional server or networking administration, management, or other topic unrelated to programming. Although the website is GitHub, this question is better suited for ServerFault in my opinion. Because of this, I am making a recommendation to close this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SSL certificate that GitHub uses simply has a subject alternative name (SAN) that lists both www.github.com and github.com. It's just a regular old certificate. DigiCert, a certificate authority, automatically creates extended validation SSL certificates in this exact fashion.

[image]